# Square root of dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, dirac-delta

Is there a measurable function $ f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+ $ so that $ f*f(x)=1 $ for all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $, i.e  $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)f(x-t) dt=1 $$ for all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: If $f\in L^1$ then $\|f\star f\|\leqslant \|f\|^2$ so $f\star f\in L^1$. And clearly $f(x)=1\notin L^1$.

Comment: Yeah. But is there any reason why $ f $ should be in $ L^1 $?

Comment: I asked this question in mathoverflow:- http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235827/square-root-of-dirac-delta-function It has been answered there.